# What was wrong about Carmine Polito's (Jeremy Renner's character) action in American Hustle?

Tags: american-hustle

I'd like to start off by saying I am not an American so I am a bit confused about how all the legal stuff works.

In *American Hustle*, Rosenfeld gets a

> fake Sheik to trap several members of the US Congress as well as Carmine Polito as part of an FBI operation. But Carmine didn't know he was fake. So he isn't in the wrong in my opinion.

From what I understood,

> Carmine took money from a Sheik to rebuild Atlantic City. Something he wanted to do for a good cause.

How is this a crime? Is it illegal for a foreign investor to invest in America and build businesses? Where is the "bribery" or "corruption" aspect in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carmine was based on [Angelo Errichetti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angelo_Errichetti#Abscam_conviction):

> Errichetti was charged with arranging for undercover agents to meet with several politicians who would end up accepting bribes to help use their influence on behalf of individuals posing as Arab investors, with Errichetti taking his share of the bribes, in what was called the Abscam case. His grip on local politics started to fade, with his three-member slate for the Camden Board of Education all losing in elections, though he was able to get all of his Democratic City Committee candidates elected in June 1980.[5] In May 1981, Errichetti was indicted on charges of bribery related to federally subsidized sewer projects, in which Errichetti was said to have received $10,000 in cash to steer engineering projects.[6]

So, he was acting as an intermediary between the "Sheikh" and congress members, in exchange for a portion of the bribes, making him an accessory to the bribery.